# How can I recfity Administration Authorization Access denied issue in dotnet 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

This code uses Authorization to allow only admin to view or manage users.
The problem is that when I uncomment the authorization tag with roles as Constants.Administration it works but when I don't it shows access denied.

[image]

#INCLUDED
 This is my Constants Class File Too

```
namespace fptbpharmarcy
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string AdministratorRole = "Administrator";
        public const string PatientRole = "Patient";
        public const string PharmarcyRole = "Pharmarcy";
        public const string EveryoneRole = "Everyone";

        public const int AdminType = 1;
        public const int PatientType = 2;
        public const int PharmarcyType = 3;

    }
}
```

//This is my startup file

```
      using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using fptbpharmarcy.Data;
using fptbpharmarcy.Models;
using fptbpharmarcy.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace fptbpharmarcy {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup (IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext> (options =>
                options.UseSqlite (Configuration.GetConnectionString ("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole> ()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext> ()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders ();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender> ();

            services.AddMvc ();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment ()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage ();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage ();

                EnsureRolesAsync (roleManager).Wait ();
                EnsureTestAdminAsync (userManager).Wait ();

            } else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler ("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles ();

            app.UseAuthentication ();

            app.UseMvc (routes => {
                routes.MapRoute (
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        private static async Task EnsureRolesAsync (RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) {
            var alreadyExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync (Constants.AdministratorRole);
            if (alreadyExists) return;
            await roleManager.CreateAsync (
                new IdentityRole (Constants.AdministratorRole));
        }

        private static async Task EnsureTestAdminAsync (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {

            var testAdmin = await userManager.Users.Where (x => x.Email == "superadmin@gmail.com").SingleOrDefaultAsync ();

            if (testAdmin != null) return;

            testAdmin = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = "superadmin", Email = "superadmin@gmail.com"
            };

            await userManager.CreateAsync (testAdmin, "SECRET@12345as");
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync (testAdmin, Constants.AdministratorRole);
        }
    }
}


 //ManageUsersController

namespace fptbpharmarcy.Controllers
{
[Authorize(Roles = Constants.AdministratorRole)]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ManageUsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ManageUsersController(
      UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
      )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;

    }


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var admin = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(Constants.AdministratorRole);
        var pharmacies = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(Constants.PharmarcyRole);
        var patients = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(Constants.PatientRole);
        var everyone = await _userManager.Users.ToArrayAsync();


        var model = new ManageUsersViewModel
        {
            Administrators = admin,
            Pharmacists = pharmacies,
            Patients = patients,
            Everyone = everyone
        };

        return View(model);
    }



}
 }
```

**SCREENSHOT OF OUTPUT- WHEN THE AUTHORIZATION IS COMMENTED**

//[Authorize(Roles = Constants.AdministratorRole)]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk6hA.png)

You can see that from the above picture none of the users with the administrative role could access the file. Please what exactly do you think might be causing these. I have spent hours trying to fix this. But to no avail.

Comment: `The problem is that when I uncomment the authorization tag with roles as Constants.Administration it works but when I don't it shows access denied.` Did you write that backwards?  From the screenshot it appears your issue is that you can only access the resource if you comment the attribute.

Either way, how do you authenticate / login?  I see you call `UseAuthentication` but I don't see anywhere that you add an authentication method such as cookies, etc.  Are you manually authenticating somewhere?

Comment: No I was logged in successfully via the logged in interface and functionality. It's just that I wasn't able to access the route that I assigned as an administrator level only accessible route via the Authorize annotation. I instead dropped the database and rerun the basic migration to get it to work. Surprisingly it worked! Not really sure why it didn't work previously.